# Authorize.net payment method help needed for magento store

Tags: magento, payment, credit-card, authorize.net

We have a magento store, payment method is everything is working but unfortunately we have got some real order with test mode and we got message like this

```
"Credit Card: xxxx-XXXX amount $47.39 authorize and capture - successful. Authorize.Net Transaction ID 0. Transaction ID: "0".
```

thats why we could not receive any payment, but main problem is we shipped product without checking received amount in our account.

So Is there any solution to charge from them. any solution appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A transaction ID of 0 means you are using a test account and not your live account It looks like someone forgot to switch the Authorize.Net account when the site when live. Switch out of test mode and put in the live account's credentials and you should be fine going forward.

Comment: yes everything is fine now. But main problem is we have got already some order and shipped product without checking authorize.net account. now is it possible to charge them anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no way to recover the credit card information without contacting the customer.